# How to create a block of the following MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, simulink

```
function [SW1, SW2]= fcn(vall)

    SW1 = ones(1,16);
    SW2 = zeros(1,16);

    % Vall is array (row vector) of 16 elements (1*16) 
    [v, idx] = sort(vall,"descend")

    for i = 1:5
       SW1(1,idx(i)) = 0;
       SW2(1,idx(i)) = 1;
    end

end
```

this is the code I used in MATLAB function but it makes the simulation process very slow, so is it possible to do the same function using only Simulink blocks?

Comment: Can you show the simulink model or better yet a minimum example of the model?

Comment: In plain MATLAB, this is faster if you do `[~,idx] = maxk(vall,5); SW1(idx) = 0; SW2(idx) = 1;` but that mileage may vary when compiling into a simulink function. I doubt that reproducing this code as blocks will make it faster, it's already pretty quick (sub 1ms on my machine) is this really the bottleneck in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response. @Wolfie my Simulink model consists of 16 MOSFETS and 3 PI controllers, this function is used to turn ON/OFF the number of switches depending on the measured variable vall, which changes very frequently and this is the only code I am using in MATLAB function. Overall simulation is extremely slow so I want to remove this MATLAB function.

Comment: Yes, This MATLAB function is a bottle neck for simulation time. without MATLAB function I give constant values to SW1 and SW2 , it take 10 to 15 minutes to complete  simulation (stop time 5000 sec). Can we bypass the MATLAB function block for some fix period of time?

Comment: The problem has been resolved by changing to discrete with a bigger step size (1e-1).  and this code can be transferred into Simulink blocks by using MUX/DMUx and Assignment blocks combination.